# Ordered List Index

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

Is there any way to get the number (index) of a `li` tag in an ordered list?

I'm trying to get the number that is shown on the side (the list numbering). I know that the traditional way is to use an id which stores the line number but this would mean that if a line is added in between, a lot of ids would have to be edited. Even though I have developed an algorithm for this, it is not so efficient.

I'm looking for a solution to use in Javascript.

Comment: The traditional way is to use ID's? Ehm... no.

Comment: Sorry, i thought so because most of the code that I saw seemed to use that method. but I must admit that my needs were a bit different from what those codes implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`previousElementSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/#attribute-previousElementSibling) to jump step-by-step to the beginning of the list and just count how many jumps you made:

```
ol.onclick = function(e) {
    var li = e.target,
        i = 1;

    while ( li.previousElementSibling ) {
        li = li.previousElementSibling;
        i += 1;   
    }

    alert( 'Index = ' + i );
};
```

Note that Element Traversal is not implemented in IE8 or below (but it is in IE9).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/U47wL/

---

If you have the `start` attribute set on the OL element, then just modify the line where `i` is declared do this:

```
i = ol.start || 1;
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/U47wL/2/

---

If you require a **cross-browser** solution, then you can use `previousSibling` and then check whether the sibling is an element node and only increment then:

```
ol.onclick = function(e) {
    var e = e || window.event,
        li = e.target || e.srcElement,
        i = ol.start || 1;

    while ( li.previousSibling ) {
        li = li.previousSibling;
        if ( li.nodeType === 1 ) { i += 1; }   
    }

    alert( 'Index = ' + i );
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/U47wL/4/

---

jQuery solution:

```
$('ol').click(function(e) {
    var n = $(e.target).index() + this.start;

    alert( 'Index = ' + n );    
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/U47wL/5/

Comment: +1 @ŠimeVidas shorter and more tricks compare to what i have, lol

Comment: I guess I'll just use previousSibling method since the number of expected list items is of the order of hundreds and getting all the elements by getElementsByTagName (as suggested in other answers) would be inefficient (correct me if i'm wrong) in terms of speed and memory). Too bad there is no direct way to get the index number. I thought that since they already have to have that data, that they would provide it!

Comment: @Diff Yep, the browsers do not provide that number. However, JavaScript libraries may provide an convenient function to retrieve the index of an element among its siblings. For instance, I use jQuery which provides an `index()` method. I will update my answer with a jQuery solution...

Comment: Well, I'm trying my best to try to avoid JQuery and thus a little script and another layer of abstraction. For one thing, I'm new to this scene and would like to learn how it actually works and for another, I'll be having a lot of script as it is, so I'm trying to avoid other libraries. But thanks anyway, and do post it, others may find it useful!

Answer (score 6):

jQuery has an `.index()` function which returns the position of the element within it's parent. That should do what you are asking for, as long as you are happy using jQuery.

For example, given the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li class="myli"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

The following javascript should return 1 (index starts from 0)

```
$('.myli').index();
```

Comment: This will not work if you use the [start](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_ol_start.asp) attribute.

Comment: In that case, `var idx = $('.myli').index() - $('.myli').parent().attr('start');`

Comment: Thanks but I'm not planning on using JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

you can try getElementsByTagName in the parent of your li elements and traverse them, and increase the index,getElementsByTagNames results in same order as they appear in DOM tree.
See this for example : http://jsfiddle.net/s3p7C/

```
<ol id='myList'>
    <li> one </li>
    <li> two </li>
    <li> three </li>
</ol>
```

---

```
var parent = document.getElementById('myList');
var elems = parent.getElementsByTagName('LI');
var res = "";
for(var i=0;i< elems.length ; i++)
{
    res +=  "li with index: " + i + " has content:" + elems[i].innerHTML;
    res += "\n";
}

alert(res);
```

Comment: This will not work if you use the [start](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_ol_start.asp) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/5jnPh/):

By clicking on the `li` node it'll `console.log` the index number

```
<ol start='5'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ol>
```

---

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.parentNode.nodeName == 'OL') {
        var els = e.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var startNum = (e.target.parentNode.getProperty('start') == undefined) ? 1 : +e.target.parentNode.getProperty('start');
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            if (els[i] === e.target) {
                console.log(i + startNum);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// 
Not especially for lists, but this is a way to get the 
index of an element within its parent, from the element itself.
It won't count any decendents of siblings, just siblings with the same tag.

```
function nthTag(who){
    var tag= who.tagName, count= 0;
    while(who){
        if(who.tagName=== tag)++count;
        who= who.previousSibling;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `previousSibling` will also fetch text nodes (the white space between LI elements).

Comment: He's right! I found that problem right at the start. But was pretty easy to figure out.