# Self referencing list items in html for ordered lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to have a self referencing 'list item' in html so when I reference a number or letter in an ordered list it keeps track of changes.  Therefore, when I add or remove list items it automatically change the references to update to the new ordered list number or letter.

If this type of self referencing is not possible in older html versions how about in html5?

Also is this type of referencing available in javascript or a javascript framework like jQuery?

Comment: By list item, do you mean `<ol><li>German Chocolate Cake<li id=spongecake>Sponge Cake</ol>`?  And by a reference, do you mean you want to be able to write something like `The tastiest of the above is <span id="spongecake"></span>` and have the `SPAN` filled in with "item 1"?  Do edits happen while the page is loaded into a browser frame, or offline?

Comment: Yes that what I mean. So I need to add an id to each list item? thx

Comment: adding an id will let you reference it from another element.  I mistyped though -- the `<span...>` should probably be something like a `<label for="spongecake>` and then you can search and replace for those using JavaScript.

Comment: The [label element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) is intended for form controls, not LI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given HTML like

```
<ol title="Figure 1">
  <li id="poundcake">Pound Cake</li>
  <li id="spongecake">Sponge Cake</li>
</ol>

<p>The most delicious from the list above is <label for="spongecake">.</p>
```

and then at the bottom (or onload),

```
<script>(function () {

  // From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395177/ordered-list-index
  function itemIndex(listItem) {
    var index = 0;
    for (var sibling = listItem; sibling;
         sibling = sibling.previousSibling) {
      if (sibling.tagName == "LI") {
        var value = +sibling.value;
        if (value) {
          return value + index;
        }
        ++index;
      }
    }
    var start = +listItem.parentNode.start || 1;
    return start + index - 1;
  }

  var labels = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
  for (var i = 0, n = labels.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var label = labels[i];
    var id = label.getAttribute("for");
    if (!id) { continue; }
    var target = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!target || target.tagName !== "LI") { continue; }
    var replacementText = (target.parentNode.title || "")
        + " item " + itemIndex(target);
    label.parentNode.replaceChild(
        document.createTextNode(replacementText), label);
  }

}())</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help: [Ordered List Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395177/ordered-list-index)